# How can I model a least squares optimization problem with absolute constrains?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, least-squares, quadratic-programming

Assume we know the values of xg, yg, a, b, m then the problem is described as follows:

```
minimize (x - xg)2 + (y - yg)2
s. t     |x - a| > m
         |x - b| > m
```

Also suggest state vector. I think X = [x; y]
In Which optimization technique like QP, least squares etc., this problem can be described ?? What should be the corresponding matrices ??

Answer (score 1):

Restating the problem:

minimize (x - x<sub>g</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y - y<sub>g</sub>)<sup>2</sup>
subject to
    |x - a| ≥ m
    |x - b| ≥ m

Algorithm:

1. y := y<sub>g</sub>
2. if feasible(x<sub>g</sub>) then x := x<sub>g</sub>; STOP
3. objbest := ∞
4. x := a-m; if feasible(x) then objbest := F(x); xbest := x
5. x := a+m; if feasible(x) and F(x)<objbest then objbest := F(x); xbest := x
6. x := b-m; if feasible(x) and F(x)<objbest then objbest := F(x); xbest := x
7. x := b+m; if feasible(x) and F(x)<objbest then objbest := F(x); xbest := x
8. x := xbest

An alternative would be an MIQP model with a binary variable or a series of QP models.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Considering this description of MIQP https://tomopt.com/docs/quickguide/quickguide006.php  Let us choose x = state vector = [x; y], what should be the following matrices: F, c, x_L, x_U, A, b_L, b_U  ??

Comment: The stated algorithm is easier and faster IMHO. I'll stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a [linear least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares), i.e. least squares quadratic objective with linear inequality constraints. Your constraints, in linear form, can be written

```
G * x <= h
```

with

```
G = [[+I, 0]
     [-I, 0]]

h = [a - m,
     -a - m]
```

with `I` the identity matrix corresponding to `x` and `0` the zeros matrix corresponding to `y`. I may have got the formulas wrong ;) But the idea is that `|x| < u` is equivalent to the two inequalities `+x < u` and `-x < u`.

You can solve your problem using either a linear least squares or quadratic programming solver, as [these two problem classes are equivalent](https://scaron.info/teaching/conversion-from-least-squares-to-quadratic-programming.html). Available solvers will depend on the programming languages you choose.